# CoreData how to add items to a NSSet which is related to an entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsset

In my project I created two entities: `Container` and `Items`. There's a one to many relationship between the two. In `Container` I called the relationship item and I set it to "To Many" because I want to have many items in each container. In `Items` I called the relationship container and I set it to "To One" because each item must be associated to one and only one container.

This aside, in my project I have a tableview where I can add new containers and when I press on a cell I can see its items. The code to create the containers is fine. The problem comes when I try to create the items: they are created successfully but they appear in each container.

In the following part I'll post the objects, how I save containers and how I save items:

- Objects:

```swift
extension Container {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Container> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Container>(entityName: "Container")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var index: Int64
    @NSManaged public var items: NSSet?

}

extension Items {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Items> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Items>(entityName: "Items")
    }

    @NSManaged public var text: String?
    @NSManaged public var image: UIImage?
    @NSManaged public var index: Int64
    @NSManaged public var container: Container?

}
```

- Creating container:

```swift
let containerEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Container", in: managedContext)!
        
        let items: NSSet = []
        
        let container = NSManagedObject(entity: containerEntity, insertInto: managedContext) as! Container
        
        ///Count is just an int variable
        container.setValue("Name", forKeyPath: "name")
        container.setValue(count, forKeyPath: "index")
        container.setValue(items, forKey: "items")
        
        do {
            try managedContext.save()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

- Creating item:

```swift
  let itemEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Items", in: managedContext)!
        
        let items = NSManagedObject(entity: itemEntity, insertInto: managedContext) as! Items
 
        items.setValue("item", forKeyPath: "text")
        items.setValue(count, forKeyPath: "index")
     
        
        do {
            try managedContext.save()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

Anyway I think that instead of creating items entities I should edit the container entity adding to it items. To do that I tried this but I feel like I'm missing something because this thing crashes.

```swift
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "container")
       
       do {
           let test = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
           
           let objectUpdate = test[containerIndex] as! NSManagedObject
           
           objectUpdate.setValue("item", forKey: "text")
           objectUpdate.setValue(count, forKey: "index")
           
           do{
               try managedContext.save()
           } catch {
               print(error)
           }
          
       }
       catch {
           print(error)
       }
```

So how can I add items to a specific container?

Plus, is it ok if two of my entities attributes are called index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If set up correctly a there should be an `addToItems()`

```
anyContainerObject.addToItems(value: Items)
```

Comment: Thank you! But how should I call this? I mean, I have to select a specific container so I assume I should go ahead with the second attempt I posted, but do I have to cast object value to Container instead of NSManagedObject? And after value, how do I create the Item to add? Do I use the first way I posted and pass the constant I called items? thank you again for your answer

Comment: You should look at the CoreData Programming Guide https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH5-SW1 and the sample code that Xcode provides when you make a new project. You would create the `Items` object the same way you make the `Container` and then you would `addToItems()` without some actual sample code of your use case I can't give you anything more specific. You have to have a `Container` not an `NSManagedObject` which you can get automatically with your FetchRequest. Try some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have set up the inverse relationships correctly in your core data model, the simplest approach is just to assign the relevant `Container` instance to the new `Item`'s `container` property.  Core data will take care of updating the `Container`'s set of `Item`s for you.

```
let itemEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Items", in: managedContext)!
        
let items = NSManagedObject(entity: itemEntity, insertInto: managedContext) as! Items
 
items.setValue("item", forKeyPath: "text")
items.setValue(count, forKeyPath: "index")
items.setValue(container, forKeyPath: "container")

do {
    try managedContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

Your code will be simpler and easier to maintain if you use the objects that are automatically created for your Core Data entities

```
        
let items = Item(context:managedObjectContext)
 
items.text = item
items.count = index
items.container = container

do {
    try managedContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

If the relationship is properly set up in the Coredata-Model,
The only thing you need to do is

> item.container = container

```
    /*let container = NSManagedObject(entity: containerEntity, insertInto: managedContext) as! Container

    let items = NSManagedObject(entity: itemEntity, insertInto: managedContext) as! Items

    let containerEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Container", in: managedContext)!

    let items = NSManagedObject(entity: itemEntity, insertInto: managedContext)*/

    //or

    let container = Container(context: managedContext)

    container.index = someIndex
    container.name = someName

    let item = Item(context: managedContext) // I think 'Item' would be better as a model name.

    item.text = someText
    item.image = someImage
    item.index = someIndex

    item.container = container // setting for Many to one relationShip

    do {
        try managedContext.save()

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```